# Slide up content of a div/span using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, slideup

I want slideup and slideup effect for content inside a div/span .
For example,

**HTML Code:**

```
<span id="test" style="background-color:#212121;" ></span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $("#test").text('testContent').slideUp(600);
```

From above code i want only the "testcontent" to slideup but,my whole span gets slideup.
Can any one help me ?????????

**Note:**
If i use fadeIn/fadeOut effects it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should add that content into another `<span>` element if you want to achieve that

```
$('<span>testContent</span>').appendTo("#test").slideUp(600);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Matei Mihai.I tried your code but its not working for me.Its not displaying content .

Comment: Do you want slideUp or slideDown?

Comment: I want my content to slideup.

Comment: @ash Try to give your inner span content with color property like `$('<span>testContent</span>').css('color','white').appendTo("#test").slideUp(600);`

Comment: @Matei Mihai : It works..For div it works fine.When i use span i can get the slideup effect but didnt get the style.